# How to set mutiple UIView in centre

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgpoint

I have tried these solutions:
**First solution**

```
ansview.center = CGPointMake(viewAnswer.frame.size.width  / 2,
                viewAnswer.frame.size.height / 2);
    ansview.center = CGPointMake(viewAnswer., viewAnswer.height/2)
```

**Second solution**

```
self.ansview.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.viewAnswer.bounds),
                CGRectGetMidY(self.viewAnswer.bounds));
```

I have already tried this code. But only one view is set to center. How to set multiple views in center?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. If you set multiple views to have the same center point then they will be on top of each other. Is that what you want? And by the way, have you turned auto-layout off? It's on by default, and with auto-layout you have to use constraints to move your views rather than changing their center points directly.

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.ansview.center = CGPointMake(self.viewAnswer.bounds.size.width / 2, self.viewAnswer.bounds.size.height / 2)
    }
```

You should use the `bounds` and not the `frame`, as the `frame` is undefined if the view has a transform.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make much sense. You can't set a view to a point, number 1. You also can't set use a view's bounds to move it. You have to use the center point, as the OP is doing. You're right that you should use the superview's bounds rather than it's frame for calculating the view's new center.

Comment: @DuncanC you´re absolutely right! Silly mistake from me, I have updated my answer. Feel free to give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try this**

```
[ansview setCenterX:self.view.centerX];
[ansview setCenterY:self.view.centerY];
```